# Jquery Validate

Tags: php, html, jquery

В общем есть форма авторизации,и есть скрипт, который проверяет валидность введенной почты, валидность пароля(длина). Так вот, как перенастроить скрипт на то, чтобы при проверке почты и пароля он проверял и символы(что-то наподобие preg_match)?
Вот сам скрипт:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function()
        {
            // Validation
            $("#sky-form").validate(
            {                   
                // Rules for form validation
                rules:
                {
                    email:
                    {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    password:
                    {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 3,
                        maxlength: 20
                    }
                },

                // Messages for form validation
                messages:
                {
                    email:
                    {
                        required: 'Вы не ввели адрес эл.почты',
                        email: 'Вы не правильно ввели адрес эл.почты'
                    },
                    password:
                    {
                        required: 'Вы не ввели пароль'
                    }
                },                  

                // Do not change code below
                errorPlacement: function(error, element)
                {
                    error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                }
            });
        });         
    </script>
```

Comment: Используете [Jquery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)? Дополните вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Используйте regex (для почты)

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

для этого вам нужно использовать [*pattern*](https://github.com/DiegoLopesLima/Validate#readme), в который можно передавать регулярное выражение

```
pattern : /^[0-9]+$/,
```